# How to know apache server deflate/gzip compression is enabled

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, gzip, deflate

My Apache server admin claims that the server has deflate/gzip compression enabled.

But when I use some standard code for introducing deflate/gzip compression in my .htaccess file, it seems there is no compression in files.

I used the below lines in `.htaccess`

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css
<FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
```

I am in doubt if the server really has enabled deflate/gzip compression. When I call `phpinfo()` it shows me the following rows related to deflate/gzip:

```
Stream Filter support           zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING            gzip, deflate
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] gzip, deflate
_ENV["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]    gzip, deflate
```

Do these lines show the server supports deflate/gzip compression or not?

And if not how should I understand?

Comment: You could always check from the returned headers. Some sites to test: http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php http://redbot.org/

Comment: problem is all such these tools show me there is no compression on the website!

Comment: If you add `<?php ob_start( 'ob_gzhandler' ); ?>` at the top of your script it will tell php/apache to compress it on output.

Comment: Thanks,I know that, but i like compression just with apache

Answer (score 1):

After quite some search, it is possible to enable compression for PHP scripts by default by setting the PHP value `zlib.compression_output = On`. This way, PHP scripts behave always like if you would put `ob_start("ob_gzhandler")` manually.

For Apache it looks like you can only set it with `SetOutputFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
`HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING gzip, deflate '`.
```

This line tells it all. It is configured.

Comment: Thanks...but really why there is no compression in my website?!

Comment: How do you know there is no compression is going?